# How can I get outside foreach loop value in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to call all the value from a foreach loop from mysql data, and use there value input into another mysql select statement. Look at my code below. It only can gather one value. I was thinking to use the first foreach loop include the whole section, however, since foreach value is individual, and I need explode array for the PDO prepare. So, at last, I want to know a way to get all value from the outside foreach loop. Appreciate.

```js
//mysql connection code, remove because it is not relative to this question
foreach ($tag_id as $term){
 $term=$term['term'].' ';//use space to seprate each one
   
 }
 echo $term:// only can can one, how can I get all result from above foreach.
 $term=explode(' ', $term);
 
 
 $stm =$db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM sign WHERE term IN (:term_0,:term_1,:ts.id, s.term, s.counter, os.user_id, os.id, COUNT(oserm_2,:term_3,:term_4,:term_5,:term_6,:term_7,:term_8,:term_9,:term_10)");

$term_0="$term[0]";
 $term_1="$term[1]";
 $term_2="$term[2]";
 $term_3="$term[3]";
 $term_4="$term[4]";
//following code is not relevive to this question.
```

Comment: `$terms .= $term['term'].' ';` instead of `$term=$term['term'].' ';`. notice the `.=` http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php. But since you are just wanting them in an array, just do `$terms[]=$term['term'];` and then it is all in an array without having to use `$term=explode(' ', $term);`

Comment: Why not use SQL join ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your last purpose to create an array from yourvalues why do you append data to a string  , just add your data to an array then directly use it .

```
foreach ($tag_id as $term){
    $term_arr[]=$term['term'];

 }

 print_r($term_arr);
```

Then you can use

```
   $stm =$db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM sign WHERE term IN (:term_0,:term_1,:ts.id, s.term, s.counter, os.user_id, os.id, COUNT(oserm_2,:term_3,:term_4,:term_5,:term_6,:term_7,:term_8,:term_9,:term_10)");

$term_0="$term_arr[0]";
    $term_1="$term_arr[1]";
    $term_2="$term_arr[2]";
    $term_3="$term_arr[3]";
    $term_4="$term_arr[4]";
```

Answer (score 8):

**Assuming that $tag_id is the array output of your mysql query**

```
$t = array();
foreach ($tag_id as $term){
    $t[]=$term['term']; // create array of terms 
 }
$str = "'".implode("','",$t)."'"; // make it a string, you can add here any other string you want to complete your query
    $stm =$db->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `sign` WHERE `term` IN (".$str.");
$stm =$db->execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

Each time you make the loop you override the vale os $term, look at this:

```
      $string = ''

        foreach ($tag_id as $term){
            $string .= $term['term'] . ' ';//use space to seprate each one

         }

         $term = $string;
   echo $term:// only can can one, how can I get all result from above foreach.
    $term=explode(' ', $term);


    $stm =$db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM sign WHERE term IN (:term_0,:term_1,:ts.id, s.term, s.counter, os.user_id, os.id, COUNT(oserm_2,:term_3,:term_4,:term_5,:term_6,:term_7,:term_8,:term_9,:term_10)");

$term_0="$term[0]";
    $term_1="$term[1]";
    $term_2="$term[2]";
    $term_3="$term[3]";
    $term_4="$term[4]";
//following code is not relevive to this question.
```

Other loop:

```
  $string = array();

    foreach ($tag_id as $term){
        $string[] = $term['term'];
     }

$term = $string;
```