# How to get a specific value inside a foreach loop and match it in another foreach loop in PHP (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have two (2) foreach loops using PHP under codeigniter. They call the same function in a controller. I want to get the value "gross_1" on the first loop then deduct it to the "gross_2" on the second loop to have a "final_gross".

Here's the Controller that I use in calling the same function (I don't have problem using these):

```
CONTROLLER:
$data['for_first_cutoff'] = $this->MyModel->my_function( $date_start_1, $date_end_1);
$data['for_second_cutoff'] = $this->MyModel->my_function( $date_start_2, $date_end_2 );

MODEL:
public function my_function($getDate_start, $getDate_end){
    $this->db->select('usr.*, att.id, ss.*');
    $this->db->from('usr');
    $this->db->join('att', 'att.id = att.id');
    $this->db->join('ss', 'ss.id = att.comp');
    $this->db->group_by('att.id');
    $this->db->where('att_date >=',$getDate_start);
    $this->db->where('att_date <=',$getDate_end);
    $query  = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Here's the view (first loop).

```
<!-- first loop -->
<?php foreach ($for_first_cutoff as $emp_1):?>

<?php 

   $num_of_days_1 = '12'; //auto computed based on "start1" and "end" dates1. 
   $salary_cutoff_1 = $emp_1['salary'];
   $gross_1 = $salary_cutoff_1 * $num_of_days_1; 
?>

   <!-- table here-->
   | <?=$emp_1['usr_fname'];?> | <?=$gross_1;?> |


<?php endforeach;?>
```

(second loop) Same content but I need to deduct the gross_1 to the gross_2 to have the final_gross:

```
<!-- Second loop -->
<?php foreach ($for_second_cutoff as $emp_2):?>

<?php 
   $num_of_days_2 = '10'; //auto computed based on "start2" and "end" dates2. 
   $salary_cutoff_2 = $emp_2['salary'];
   $gross_2 = $salary_cutoff_2 * $num_of_days_2; 

   $final_gross = $gross_1 - $gross_2;
?>

   <!-- table here-->
  | <?=$emp_2['usr_fname'];?> | <?=$gross_2;?> | <?=$final_gross;?> |


<?php endforeach;?>
```

The HTML look like this:

```
Loop 1
| John Doe | $100 |
| Sarah Doe | $0 |

Loop 2
| John Doe | $50 | $150 |
| Sarah Doe | $2 | $150 | <---- this is wrong. It must be only $2.
```

I tried using the approach found in this [post] ([How can I get outside foreach loop value in this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869540/how-can-i-get-outside-foreach-loop-value-in-this-situation)) but I don't know how to implement it using my structure.

Comment: This looks wrong: `$final_gross = $gross_1 - $gross_2;` What is the value of `$gross_1` in this loop? It looks like you need to store an array of `$gross_1` values for each employee when you're doing your first loop, and retrieve the appropriate value to use in the second loop.

Comment: the join `$this->db->join('att', 'att.id = att.id');` wouldn't work - you have to join something from your user table here - and second what happens if John Doe have - for some reason - two values within one of your dates ?

Comment: @kmoser the value of $gross_1 is $100, $gross_2 is $50

Comment: @sintakonte i am joining other tables there. That part is working fine, I have no problem with that. The reason i included the  JOIN there is just to show that I am joining other table not just the USR table.

Comment: yeah and my second question ?

Comment: @kmoser. Yes, that's what I need to to exactly but I don't know how to insert that in my first loop.

Comment: @sintakonte the salary is under USR. No joining needed I think?

Comment: what happens if - for some reason - you have John Doe twice in one of your loops (e.g. in Loop 1) ... - you have to provide more informations what you want - because right now its hard to understand

Comment: @sintakonte if John Doe happens to have two values, they will be grouped.. `$this->db->group_by('att.id');`

Comment: @sintakonte you can actually disregard the JOIN part there. the values I want to get is under the USR table. the Salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright - based on the comments you can try the following

create an array which saves your data from the first loop - i used as key `att.id` (should probably your user_id) - and access to this array from your first loop with your id from the second one

```
<!-- first loop -->
<?php 
    $arrGrossData = [];
    foreach ($for_first_cutoff as $emp_1):
?>

<?php 

   $num_of_days_1 = '12'; //auto computed based on "start1" and "end" dates1. 
   $salary_cutoff_1 = $emp_1['salary'];
   $gross_1 = $salary_cutoff_1 * $num_of_days_1; 
   $arrGrossData[$emp_1['att.id']] = $gross_1;
?>

   <!-- table here-->
   | <?=$emp_1['usr_fname'];?> | <?=$gross_1;?> |


<?php endforeach;?>


<!-- Second loop -->
<?php foreach ($for_second_cutoff as $emp_2):?>

<?php 
   $num_of_days_2 = '10'; //auto computed based on "start2" and "end" dates2. 
   $salary_cutoff_2 = $emp_2['salary'];
   $gross_2 = $salary_cutoff_2 * $num_of_days_2; 

   $final_gross = (isset($arrGrossData[$emp_2['att.id']])) ? $arrGrossData[$emp_2['att.id']] - $gross_2 : $gross_2;
?>

   <!-- table here-->
  | <?=$emp_2['usr_fname'];?> | <?=$gross_2;?> | <?=$final_gross;?> |


<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for letting me understand what should I do. Cheers mate!